# Change DateField value using Provider

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to change date field value while clicking on a Radio Button named "Yes". One can input date by changing date from datepicker. Another one is is user clicked on "Yes" button the datefield value will be changed. I'm trying it using Provider. But the updated value isn't displaying into datefield instantly.

Code snippet:

```
DateTimeFormField(
    dateFormat: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'),
    mode: DateTimeFieldPickerMode.date,
    initialValue: DateTime.parse(list[index].endDate!),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      isDense: true,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.w, vertical: 10.h),
      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
      errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.event_note),
    ),
    onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
      list[index].endDate = value.toString();
    },
  )

##
class ManipulateDate extends ChangeNotifier {
  String date = '';

  void setDateToDTNow(String newDate) {
    date = newDate;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Inside Button's onPressed function

Provider.of<ManipulateDate>(context, listen: false).setDateToDTNow(DateTime.now().toString());
```

How could I set the changed value `Provider.of<ManipulateDate>(context).date` into `list[index].endDate` and *the value will display instantly while clicking on Button.*

Comment: try listen:true instead of false

Comment: It gives an error. ``Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.``

Comment: Did you declare the provider as a root widget?

Comment: yes. I've declared it

Answer (score 1):

I guess I got the issue you have set listen: false -

```
Provider.of<ManipulateDate>(context, listen: false).setDateToDTNow(DateTime.now().toString());
```

So when you do notifylisteners() the above won't be triggered or updated so try changing that to true -

```
Provider.of<ManipulateDate>(context, listen: true).setDateToDTNow(DateTime.now().toString());
```

Or alternatively you can use a consumer widget around the part which you want to update in the UI. Hope these helps now....

Comment: It's for while I'll select a date. But I want to change the date while clicking on a button/radio button. When I clicked on that button I need to change the datefield value.

Comment: then just place the setState inside that function body with  list[index].endDate = Provider.of<ManipulateDate>(context).date inside it. When you click it will instantly change and update the UI.

Comment: I've to change the date value from outside of datefield. Not selecting the date by clicking on calendar. It has two function. One can select date from DateField calendar. Another condition is if user clicked on Yes Radio Button(which is another field into the form) Then I've to change datefield value. Got it?

Comment: ohh okie., sorry for misinterpreting I will update the answer.

Comment: Ok Sodha. It's two part. 1. datefield will change by selecting date from datepicker. 2. If I clickied on Yes button the datefield value will be changed according to the condition. For that I'm using Provider

Comment: if you have error about - Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree, check the answer -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60083895/tried-to-listen-to-a-value-exposed-with-provider-from-outside-of-the-widget-tre

Comment: this show while I'm setting listen: true. listen: false don't show any error

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because you're not listening to the provider changes in your `build` method, so the widget doesn't get "refreshed" when the provider is updated. Check [`ChangeNotifierProvider`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html) for some examples.

BTW, I highly recommend using [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) over `Provider`, as it offers a cleaner widget tree, and more flexibility in state management.

For example, you could do this:

```dart
// Outside of your class...
// Yes, as a global, but don't worry. That's actually the correct way to do it.
final selectedDateProvider = StateProvider((ref) => DateTime.now());

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final DateTime selectedDate = ref.watch(selectedDateProvider).state;
  
  return DateTimeFormField(
    initialValue: selectedDate,
    ...
    onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
      ref.read(selectedDateProvider).state = value;
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Getting value from selected date isn't a issue. I need to set the datetime while I'm clicking on Radio button named "Yes".

Comment: @pasha With `Riverpod`, that's easy to do. You would wrap your radio button widget with a `Consumer` widget, which would give you access to the `ref` needed to access the providers tree.

However, as I wrote above, most likely the issue is not with the updating of the state (as you did not report any errors from that), but with how you're reading (listening to) the provider.